# IE6 Shrink-wrap with Rounded Corners

Tags: html, css, width, internet-explorer-6

In FF and IE8 things look pretty good.  I have a mock up of the drop down that I'm trying to create with rounded corners at bottom here: [www.geowinedb.org/drop-down-test/test.html](http://www.geowinedb.org/drop-down-test/test.html).  In IE6 the mega `div` is extending to the far left edge of the window.  What do I need to change/add (e.g. underscore hacks) to get the drop-down to shrink-wrap its contents (the `ul`).

p.s. I'll be back to ask about the `z-index` problem that blocks the drop-down (IE6 again), but if anyone want to answer that as well it will be much appreciated.

EDIT 20091107: More specifics on the requirements: It must work in IE6+ and the drop down menus cannot be fixed width.  The client wants to be able to change menu item text at will and have the drop-downs size automatically.

EDIT 20091111: I never did find a great solution.  The menu along with some other requirements for hover changes, meant that JavaScript was necessary.  So, I found that I could position each main menu item absolute, then position each sub-menu `div` absolute (this solved the `z-index` problem), and lastly I computed the width from the underlying `ul` and set the outer `div` width.  Then the rounded corners positioned themselves correctly on all the browsers that I needed.

Comment: Why dont you just display these for IE6 users: http://www.thedonutproject.com/2009/05/22/overly-judgemental-ie6-splash-pages/

Answer (score 0):

Does it bother to use fixed width for your UL (and maybe `UL.mega-b` too) ? because this way you will definitely avoid this problem.

`display:block` in your UL can also be the cause of this.

Comment: Thanks Soufiane. I can't use fixed width. But, took your advice and re-worked the `display: block`. I noticed to that adding `float: left` to the `mega-b` helps a lot in IE6, but then I lose the rounded corners. I updated the test pages with these changes.